# Why can't anonymous visitors flag?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, anonymous, anonymous-visitors

The dreaded Hot Questions sidebar of shame led me to [Latin translation](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1846/latin-translation) on [Italian Language beta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/), where I have never posted (so am anonymous). I want to ping one of their moderators and warn them that this question, [off topic by their site's nascent standards](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/shouldnt-we-allow-questions-regarding-the-latin-language/109#109), is going to be attracting the 'wrong sort of attention', via its appearance on Hot Questions.

But as an anonymous visitor, all I can do to the question is share or (suggest an) edit. Why can't I flag? If a post were spam or offensive, wouldn't we want anonymous visitors to be able to help identify it as such?

Comment: Why not just join, takes just a couple of clicks when you're already established on SE?

Comment: @ChrisBallard that works for *my* case; I'm asking about the *general* case.

Comment: Sure. just saying though, as that's what I normally do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the mods already get tons of bad flags from registered users asking for answers to their questions and such. Let's not make that easier to do.

Also, it would require major changes to the spam flag system, currently they are internally treated as a kind of vote (and when 6 votes are achieved, the post is deleted and the author gets -100). Not something that ought to be easier to abuse.

Comment: Not to mention even a registered user must obtain 15 rep before they can flag. If you just join to flag you'll get the bonus 100 rep if you can and flag away.

Answer (score 0):

Answerifying an earlier comment from JonW:

In addition to any other reasoning, flagging [requires a certain amount of reputation](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), which obviously anonymous visitors don't and can't have.