# Be able to flag on other SE sites without being registered there

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

Flags are pretty much the same across all SE sites. Even if you are not knowledgeable on a particular site (say, Cooking SE), you're probably still capable of telling whether something is off-topic, inappropriate, spam, etc.

To flag, you need to be logged in that site. To log in, you need to register.

I suggest that if the system knows that you're logged in as a trusted user in another SE site, then it should let you flag posts regardless or being registered/logged in this particular site.

I know that registering is very quick if you have an account in another SE site. It even gives you bonus reputation. But I still wouldn't want to add another site just for the sake of flagging something. I could delete my account, yes, but that's kind of annoying.

And of course, I could just leave it be and let someone from that site handle/flag it. But hey, the more help the better, no? :]

Comment: Very similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226830/why-cant-anonymous-visitors-flag (it's mine)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is a good idea.

I registered on most sites for the sole purpose of spam/rude offensive flagging. In that perspective I'm sure anyone can spot and make a correct judgement call if a flag is warranted.

For the not an answer, low quality and specially close flags I think it depends on the community and their consensus on effective flagging. I doubt *outsiders* that don't participate on the site can make the correct decision based on their experience on other sites.

If you find something on site you're not a member and don't want to create an account you can always hop in chat, for example in [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) or in the site specific chat room and ask for someone else to take a look.

I think the benefit from the change you propose is limited and will not dramatically change the overall quality of the content in the SE network.